# What are the new features available to bash 4?

Tags: shell, bash

I was using bash3 up to now, and just got a copy of the latest version

```
$ ./bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
```

What are the major changes/feature additions in version 4 over version 3?

Comment: As an aside, one can get the current running version of bash by typing Ctrl^xv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [NEWS file](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) lists the features that were added in each version.

Most notably in 4.0 I see a couple of improvements to the autocompletion infrastructure, the (optional) addition of the `**` glob operator, associative arrays and various syntactic shortcuts.

Comment: Also the `autocd` option — it doesn't look like much, but as a zsh user, it's what I miss most when I occasionally use bash (<4 or unconfigured).

Answer (score 2):

Most importantly for the behavior of old scripts, the behavior with `set -e` has slightly changed, among other things for `( ...)`, `[[ ... ]]`, and `(( ... ))`.

The new behavior is said to be documented in the manual.

For example:

```
$ bash3 -ec '(false); echo $?'
1
$ bash4 -ec '(false); echo $?'
$
```